# Get full path to the nested object's field in C#

Tags: c#

Lets say we have two classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass2 Foo { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public int Blah { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to display the full path to the Blah property but without including the namespace, so in this case, the expected result would be:

```
MyClass.Foo.Blah
```

I've run the stuff in the debug mode and dag in the `MyClass` object using reflection `typeof(MyClass)`.
In the end, I found the Blah property in the tree using the expression:

```
((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[])((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)((System.Reflection.MemberInfo[])((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)((System.Reflection.RuntimeFieldInfo)((System.Reflection.FieldInfo[])((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)typeof(MyClass)).DeclaredFields)[0]).DeclaringType).DeclaredMembers)[0]).ReturnType).DeclaredProperties)[0]
```

which looks a bit clunky. 
Anybody knows some "smart" way how can I receive the result but without hardcoding the names of the fields? Cheers

Comment: What kind of input are you planning to give this function?

Comment: Whatever you want. But does it really matter?

Comment: I can't provide you a C# function unless you specify the inputs the function has access to. For instance, is this function evaluating a text file containing C# code? Or is it being passed a reference to an instance of `MyClass` and told to find a member or member-of-member with the name `Blah`? Or is it being passed instances of `PropertyInfo` and other reflection objects, etc.? It could also help to clarify why you're asking for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way I can think of is

```
Type cType = typeof(MyClass);
var prop = cType.GetProperties()[0];
var innerPropName = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties()[0].Name;
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(MyClass)}.{prop.Name}.{innerPropName}");
```

---

**Edit**

I have used recursive function in order to be able to loop through the Properties

```
public static string GetClassDetails(Type t, ref IList<string> sList, string str = null )
{
    if (sList is null) sList = new List<string>();
    if (str is null) str = t.Name;

    foreach (var propertyInfo in t.GetProperties())
    {
        str = $"{str}.{propertyInfo.Name}";
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
            str = $"{str}.{GetClassDetails(propertyInfo.PropertyType, ref sList, str)}";

        sList.Add(str);
        str = "";
    }

    return str;
}
```

You can call it

```
 IList<string> sList = null;
 var result = GetClassDetails(cType, ref sList);
```

Example Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass2 Foo { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public int Blah { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but what if I add some new fields to this class in the future? Not sure if `[0]` is flexible enough

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ToString` method of an expression to get the path. Minimal modification is needed to replace the lambda part (`x => x`) with `YourClassName`:

```
usage: ReflectionHelper<MyClass>.GetPath(x => x.Foo.Blah) // -> "MyClass.Foo.Blah"

public class ReflectionHelper<T>
{
    public static string GetPath<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expr)
    {
        var name = expr.Parameters[0].Name;

        return expr.ToString()
            .Replace($"{name} => {name}", typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```